# How to put a line after each grouping rows in a GridView?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I am using a GridView that has many rows with the same values, so I grouped these rows using [GridViewHelper class](http://www.agrinei.com/gridviewhelper/gridviewhelper_en.htm). Now I want to put a separate line between each grouping values. How to do that?

The following snapshot shows you the current situation:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't sure if you wanted to style them when rendered or when you click the row.  So here is both.  You can decide what styles you want.  :-)

Set the appropriate attributes in your ASP.NET GridView control for controlling CSS:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gridviewid" 
                      runat="server" 
                      CssClass="gridview" 
                      AutoGenerateSelectButton="True" 
                      GridLines="None"
                      AllowPaging="true"
                      PageSize="10">
            <HeaderStyle CssClass="gridViewHeader" />
            <RowStyle CssClass="gridViewRow" />
            <AlternatingRowStyle CssClass="gridViewAltRow" />
            <SelectedRowStyle CssClass="gridViewSelectedRow" />
            <PagerStyle CssClass="gridViewPager" />
        </asp:GridView>


protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        e.Row.CssClass = "cssClass";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like...

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GridViewHelper helper = new GridViewHelper(this.GridView1);
    helper.RegisterGroup("yourGroupName", true, true);
    helper.GroupHeader += new GroupEvent(helper_GroupHeader);
}

private void helper_GroupHeader(string groupName, object[] values, GridViewRow row)
{
    if (groupName == "yourGroupName" )
    {
        row.Cells[0].Text = "<br />" + row.Cells[0].Text;
    }
}
```

You should also be able to insert a new one before `row` instead of just adding a break line to the cell if that's what you want.

Comment: sorry but the class that is mentioned in the link that I put in my question is called GridViewGroup not GridViewHelper. When I changed the class name, nothing happened. Could you please have a look at it?